# change permissions of file for remote machine

Tags: python, jenkins, file-permissions, python-2.6, permission-denied

I am generating csv report using below code and using jenkins job for triggering and file is created on remote machine.
But I am getting this error `(report not generated due to [Errno 13] Permission denied: )`

```
def generate_csv_report(self, failure_list):
    try:
        file_exists = os.path.isfile(
            os.path.join(self.config.get("module_time_update_path"),
                         'failure_report.csv'))
        with open(os.path.join(self.config.get("module_time_update_path"),
                               'failure_report.csv'), "a") as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['Username', 'Change Id',
                                                   'Weblink', 'Program',
                                                   'Hardware',
                                                   'mission Exception',
                                                   'Failure Reason'],
                                    lineterminator='\r')
            if not file_exists:
                writer.writerow(
                    dict((fn, fn) for fn in writer.fieldnames))
            writer.writerows(failure_list)
            f.close()
        logging.info("failure report generated successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(str(e))
```

**How to resolve this permisison error??**

Answer (score 0):

The PermissionError can also occur when the file is open.
Did you check this was not the case?

Otherwise check that you have all the necessary rights to access your remote machine and write there.

Comment: file is not opened I need to use os.chmod but I don't know how to use it in above code.